# abstract class, but all its methods have implementation

Tags: java, abstract-class, implementation

I start working with jackson library. It has this class:

```
public abstract class TypeReference<T> implements Comparable<com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference<T>> {
    protected final Type _type;

    protected TypeReference() {
        Type superClass = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        if (superClass instanceof Class) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Internal error: TypeReference constructed without actual type information");
        } else {
            this._type = ((ParameterizedType)superClass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        }
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return this._type;
    }

    public int compareTo(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference<T> o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So it is abstract class, but all its methods have implementation. My question is: Why? Why use abstract class when all its methods have implementation? Why not just use not abstract class?

Here is simple illustration:

```
package com.company;

abstract class MyClass1 {
    void  method1() {};
    abstract void  method2();
}

abstract class MyClass2 {
    void  method1() {};
    void  method2() {};
}

class MyClass3 {
    void  method1() {};
    void  method2() {};
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass1 obj1 = new MyClass1() {
            @Override
            void method2() {}
        };
        MyClass2 obj2 = new MyClass2() {};
        MyClass3 obj3 = new MyClass3() {};
    }
}
```

Initialization of obj2 and obj3 is the same. So why use MyClass2 instead of MyClass3?

Comment: "*My question is: Why?*" - you must ask the author(s), we can only guess: maybe to avoid having an instance of that class created directly, eventually to force it to be sub-classed to be able to determine the `_type`. BTW `new MyClass3() {}` is creating an (anonymous) sub-class of `MyClass3` (and an instance of that sub-class)

Comment: All of the _methods_ are implemented, but it can't do its job, which requires some subtlety with reflection and generics, without a subclass.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs of [TypeReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html):

> This generic abstract class is used for obtaining full generics type information by sub-classing;

It makes no sense to have instances of this class, because you can't extract generic type information from it, only from concrete subclasses, hence it's abstract.